# Looking up foreign symbols by name in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

One can quickly look up symbols by name in Visual Studio by hitting *Ctrl-,* (*Navigate To*, at least in VS2013) - but that searches only symbols defined in the solution itself.

Often times one wants to look up metadata for symbols defined in system and third-party assemblies the project is linking against.

I usually find myself to write the symbol down in some line and hit F12 on it.

Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: Try the object explorer.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Why don't you try it yourself? Then you'd know that it's a worse experience than the workaround I'm using.

Comment: That *is* what I used to do. I found it better because I could use it while running code, without having to edit and continue. I now have Resharper, but I didn't suggest it as it's not free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) extension simple press CTRL + T and type in the symbol name like this:

[image]

When you select the symbol resharper tries to show it (local code file, symbol server or even via decompiler [e.g. for closed source .NET code]).

I know Resharper is not free, but you can safe a lot of time with this tool. It brings a lot of productivity features to Visual Studio.